# Type() function of python

Tags: python-3.x, class, types, python-class

Below is the code which I tried once

```
 class try1 :
    a = 0

 box = type(try1())
 print(box)
```

This was the output

```
<class '__main__.try1'>
```

Now I changed my code a little

```
class try1:
   a = 0
    
box = type(try1())
print((type(box)))
```

This is the output then

```
<class 'type'>
```

Now I know that type() function is used to return class type of the given parameter. Can anyone please help me in understanding what applying type() function on a variable (i.e. box ) which already stores type of another class (i.e. try1) is giving this output ?

Comment: The code that you posted is syntactically incorrect and produces syntax errors. Please paste your _actual_ code. Pay special attention to class names and indentation.

Comment: thanks a lot...corrections are done

Comment: Your indentation is still illegal.

Comment: Also, consider giving the second class a different name (e.g., `try2`). You will see that the second class is impossible if defined alone, without the first class.

Comment: Second code is in different python file

Comment: You cannot create an object of type `try1` in the body of the namesake class. Basically, your example works only because you first created the first `try1`. And it is still syntactically illegal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `type` is not a function, but a class. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type)

Maybe this code makes it a bit clearer:

```
class try1 :
    a = 0


instance = try1()
box = type(instance)
print(box)
print((type(box)))

# the type of the instance object is it's class
assert box is try1
# but classes themselves are objects too
assert isinstance(try1, object)
# and because box is try1
assert type(box) is type(try1)
# to be more specific, the class of a class is type
assert isinstance(try1, type)
assert type(try1) is type
# and therefore
assert repr(type(try1)) == "<class 'type'>"


# we could have created the try1 class by using the type class:
try1 = type('try1', (), {'a': 0})
# and end up with exactly the same thing
assert try1().a == 0
assert repr(type(try1())) == "<class '__main__.try1'>"

# well almost... we just created a new class and rehung the try1 to point to it
# box still points to the old try1
# so they may look the same
assert repr(try1) == repr(box)  # "<class '__main__.try1'>"
# they are different classes
assert not (try1 is box)
```

All variables in Python are just names that point to something. `class try1:` is just syntactic sugar to make a type with a `__name__` of try1 and let the name try1 in our namespace point to it.